# bash- get all lines with the same column value in two files

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, uniq

I have two text files each with 3 fields. I need to get the lines with the same value on the third field. The 3rd field value is unique in each file. Example:

file1:

> 1 John 300
>   2 Eli  200
>   3 Chris 100
>   4 Ann 600

file2:

> 6 Kevin 250
>   7 Nancy 300
>   8 John  100

output:

> 1 John 300
>   7 Nancy 300
>   3 Chris 100
>   8 John  100

When I use the following command:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -k 3 | uniq -c -f 2
```

I get only one row from an input file with the duplicate value. I need both!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this one-liner gives you that output:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$0;next}$3 in a{print a[$3];print}' file1 file2
```

Comment: @user3490988 awk first read file1, save all lines in a "hashtable" key is 3rd column, value is the line. then processes 2nd file, check if 3rd column of file2.line in the "hashtable", if found, print the corresponding line (a[$3]) and the file2.line. If you don't know the syntax of awk, it is hard to explain in very detail. I suggest you reading the awk's man page.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is

```
join -1 3 -2 3 <(sort -k3 file1) <(sort -k3 file2) | awk '{print $2, $3, $1; print $4, $5, $1}'
```

or

```
join -1 3 -2 3 <(sort -k3 file1) <(sort -k3 file2) -o "1.1 1.2 0 2.1 2.2 0" | xargs -n3
```